# Retrieve a particular value based on the Key from JSON Data using Python 3

Tags: python, json

I am trying to retrieve a particular value from a JSON data.

This is the API that gives JSON Data :- http://data.ehealthireland.ie/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=967673a3-1ce0-47e0-8e09-c876894ad489

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://data.ehealthireland.ie/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=967673a3-1ce0-47e0-8e09-c876894ad489'  
fileobj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print (fileobj.read())
```

How can I access the first Speciality Value in the JSON Data ?

The answers for the Identified duplicate question doesn't help me to understand the problem in this question. Sorry.

Comment: The answers for the Identified duplicate question doesn't help me to understand the problem in this question. Sorry.

Comment: I tried this **SpecialtyName= fileobj['records']['Specialty'][1]** and it didn't help.

Comment: Use `d = json.loads(fileobj.read().decode())`
`SpecialtyName = d['result']['records'][0]['Speciality']`

Comment: Yes, That works for me. Thanks.

Comment: what you get you must convert it to a string and then convert it to a dictionary, then you use the magic of the keys and index.